# Выборка изображений php

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать заглушку noimage если у товара нет картинки (тобишь вообще нет строки в таблице images для товара).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE product_id='$id' ORDER BY sort ASC LIMIT 5";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row) { $image = $row['image'];  

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $image = "../ui/img/noimage.jpg";
  } 
...
```

Заглушка не появляется. Если же я делаю проверку и вывожу для всех товаров этот noimage, то всё работает и у товаров у которых есть эта строка в таблице, появляется noimage.

```
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        $image = "../ui/img/noimage.jpg";
      }
```

Если просто вывести `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)` то у товаров которые с картинками появляется число строк, а у которых нет картинок не выводится ничего. В чём ошибка? Может быть дело в конструкции. Привожу полный код:

```
<div uk-slider>
<div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabindex="-1" loading="lazy">
<ul class="uk-slider-items uk-grid uk-grid-match">

<?

$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE product_id='$id' ORDER BY sort ASC LIMIT 5";

if($result = $conn->query($sql)){

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  $image = "../ui/img/noimage.jpg";

 ?>

  <li>
  <a href=product.php?id=<?echo $id?>><img src="<?echo $image?>" style="object-fit:cover; max-height:400px; min-height:400px; width:100%;"></a>
  </li>

<?

} else if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

foreach($result as $row) { $image = $row['image'];  

?>

  <li>
  <a href=product.php?id=<?echo $id?>><img src="<?echo $image?>" style="object-fit:cover; max-height:400px; min-height:400px; width:100%;"></a>
  </li>

<?

}}} else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

?>

</ul>

    <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
    <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>
  
</div>

<ul id = "dotnav-category" class="uk-slider-nav uk-dotnav uk-flex-center"></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_num_rows` показывает сколько записей было извлечено для запроса. Зачем оно вам надо - неизвестно.

Если в таблице отсутствие картинке - `null`, то и проверять надо на это значение:

```
if (is_null($row['image'])) {
    $image = "../ui/img/noimage.jpg";
}
```

Для *PHP7.0* можно написать проще:

```
 $image = $row['image'] ?? "../ui/img/noimage.jpg";
```

---

По вновь добавленному коду: вы добавляете ссылки на страницу только тогда, когда есть картинки, сооветственно, если её нет, надо тоже отображать что-то...а вы этого не делаете. То есть не хватает `li a`  с текстом в блоке `if`

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` использую потому что так можно посмотреть сколько строк в таблице images для определённого товара. Если строк нет, то высвечивать заглушку. не работают ваши варианты(

Comment: В итоге не ясно.... ты хочешь высвечивать что картинки нет для каждой строки, если там нет картинки или если вообще не нашлось товаров в принципе? На данный момент ты пытаешься сделать именно второе....для первого варианта я корректно написал. Скорее всего ты не так это вставил в свой код или интерпретировал

Comment: У меня есть 2 таблицы: с товарами и с картинками к ним. Если у товара нет картинки, то соответственно в таблице с картинками отсутствует строка с этим айдишником товара. Вот для него и нужно вывести noimage

Comment: В таком случае (судя по добавленному коду) ты добавляешь ссылки на страницу только тогда, когда есть картинки, сооветственно если её нет, надо тоже отображать что-то...а ты этого не делаешь, То есть не хватает `li a ` с текстом в блоке if

Comment: Точно, я почему-то думал, что переменная будет браться либо из одного if либо из другого) Привёл рабочий вариант в посте.

Answer (score 0):

судя  по представленному коду `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {` входит в блок `foreach($result as $row) {` то есть когда есть записи, то проверка на нумроуз..понятно, что она не будет никогда выполнена, поскольку туда мы попадаем если нумроуз не 0.
Попробуйте такой код

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){ 
$image = "../ui/img/noimage.jpg"; 
?> 
<li>
  <a href=product.php?id=<?echo $id?>><img src="<?echo $image?>" style="object-fit:cover; max-height:400px; min-height:400px; width:100%;"></a>
    
</li>
<?
} else { foreach($result as $row) { $image = $row['image'];  

?>

  <li>
  <a href=product.php?id=<?echo $id?>><img src="<?echo $image?>" style="object-fit:cover; max-height:400px; min-height:400px; width:100%;"></a>
    
  </li>

<?
}}} else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}
```

Comment: попробовал вынести за форич, но тоже не работает. посмотрите в моём посте, в полный код добавил результат.

Comment: ну щас, если нумроуз равно нулю, то переменная `image` принимает значение, но в шаблоне не выводится как я вижу.

Comment: в текущем виде у вас нет вывода при нумроуз равным нулю..я попробовал создать вам код, посмотрите.